# Is it possible to create HierarchicalGraphMachine from HierarchicalMachine derived model instance using transitions

Tags: python, transition

I have a model class like

```
class MyModel(HierarchicalMachine):
    Machine.__init__(self, states=self.states, transitions=self.transitions,  
                                                    initial='EstablishingWsConnection')
...
```

which works fine.

Now I would like to create a HierarchicalGraphMachine from my model like

```
model = MyModel()
GraphMachine = mfact.get_predefined(graph=True, nested=True)  
grMachine =self.GraphMachine(                        
                    send_event=False, 
                    auto_transitions=False, 
                    title="BootNotificationStates",
                    show_conditions=True)  
hgm = HierarchicalGraphMachine(model, grMachine)

hgm.model.show_graph('mystate.png')
```

results in
[mystate.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fl1Q.png)

Is it possible to reuse my model instance for drawings?

Thx,

val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40871072/1617563) answer already states, the recommended solution is to nest your `HierarchicalStateMachine` into a `HierarchicalGraphMachine`. Right now `transitions` contains a [bug](https://github.com/tyarkoni/transitions/issues/164) which influences the way nested states are parsed. That's why it looks a bit weird. This will be fixed soon! Eventually, this:

**Solution 1: Nesting**

```
from transitions.extensions import MachineFactory as factory

HSM = factory.get_predefined(nested=True)
GraphHSM = factory.get_predefined(nested=True, graph=True)

class MyModel(HSM):
    def __init__(self):
        self.states = ['A', 'B', 'C']
        self.transitions = [['go', 'A', 'B'],
                            ['go', 'B', 'C'],
                            ['go', 'C', 'A']]
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(self, states=self.states,       
                                      transitions=self.transitions,
                                      auto_transitions=False, initial='A')

mymodel = MyModel()

# define the nesting for the new machine
states = [{'name': 'mymodel', 'children': mymodel}]
# set the initial state to A of mymodel. Replace the underscore
# with the seperatore you are using
graph_machine = GraphHSM(states=states, auto_transitions=False,
                         title="Reused Machine", initial="mymodel_A")
graph_machine.graph.draw('reuse.png', prog='dot')
```

Should result in this:
[image]

Again, this is the recommended way. However, if you **really** need to have your states at the root level of the newly created machine, you can tinker around with the internals of both machines and monkey patch your way to glory. `transitions` manages its central parts in two collections: A list with `states` and a dictionary with `events` (which contain state transitions). The second thing to know is that a transition will update the graph when it is valid. Objects of the type `NestedTransition` do not know how to do that. So this is what you could do:

**Solution 2: Patching**

```
# Create a new graph_machine which is initialized in mymodel's  state
graph_machine = GraphHSM(mymodel, title="Patched Machine",
                         states=[mymodel.state],
                         initial=mymodel.state)
# shallow copy the core parts to the new machine
graph_machine.events = mymodel.events
graph_machine.states = mymodel.states
# reinitialize the graph with the new configuration
mymodel.get_graph(force_new=True)

# 'upcast' the transitions to be of the type NestedGraphTransition
from transitions.extensions.factory import NestedGraphTransition
for event in mymodel.events.values():
    event.machine = graph_machine
    for lists in event.transitions.values():
        for transition in lists:
            transition.__class__ = NestedGraphTransition
# use the machine and test if the graph has been updated
mymodel.go()
mymodel.graph.draw('patching.png', prog='dot')
```

As a result you will get this:
[image]

I do not know how bullet proof the second solution is but I wanted to leave it here as a bit of *extended* documentation of how `transitions` operates... and of course I was curious if it actually works ;P.

Answer (score 1):

A `GraphMachine` is not what `mfact.get_predefined(graph=True, nested=True)` will give you. That would be `mfact.get_predefined(graph=True)`. What you call `GraphMachine` here, is already `HierarchicalGraphMachine`.

To get this straight, you may create an `HierarchicalGraphMachine` like in the following snippet.

```
from transitions import Machine
from transitions.extensions import MachineFactory

myStates = ['walking', 'running']
myTransitions = [ { 'trigger': 'accelerate', 'source': 'walking', 'dest': 'running' } ]

graphNestedMachineClass = MachineFactory.get_predefined(
    graph=True, nested=True)
hierarchicalGraphMachine = graphNestedMachineClass(
    states=myStates, transitions=myTransitions, initial='walking')
```

If you want to embed any type of a `Machine` inside a `HierarchicalGraphMachine` and use a model, you can add the following code to the above snippet.

```
class MyModel(object):
    pass

myModel = MyModel()

moreStates = [
    'waiting',
    {'name': 'moving', 'children': hierarchicalGraphMachine }
]
moreTransitions = [
    { 'trigger': 'wait', 'source': '*', 'dest': 'waiting'},
    {'trigger': 'move', 'source': 'waiting', 'dest': 'moving_walking'}
]

parentHierarchicalGraphMachine = graphNestedMachineClass(
    model=myModel, states=moreStates, transitions=moreTransitions, initial='waiting')
```

Now you can transit between states like so:

```
print myModel.state  # prints 'waiting'
myModel.move()
print myModel.state  # prints 'move_walking'
myModel.accelerate()
print myModel.state  # prints 'move_running'
myModel.wait()
print myModel.state  # prints 'waiting'
```

And you could use e.g. `myModel.graph.draw('mystate.png', prog='dot')` to generate a state diagram like the following one.

[image: mystate.png]

For further details, please consider having a look into the source code of the transitions `factory.py`, located in the `transition/extension` path of the transitions repository. And also have a look at the very good `README.md` in the top directory of the very same repository.

The transitions repository is available via GitHub at https://github.com/tyarkoni/transitions.